# Can we have the category of integers?

Tags: category-theory

In beginning to learn category theory, I've tried to come up with my own examples of categories.

Could we have a category **Int**, where the objects are integers, and arrows, all mappings between integers?

If you can't (which I suspect might be the case), what *can't* be an object/arrow?

Comment: What do you mean by a mapping between integers?

Comment: @lulu : well if you see an integee as a finite ordinal (which is the most common definition if I'm not mistaken), "mappings between integers" makes perfetc sense

Comment: @lulu; that's actually part of my problem. For **Set**, arrows are functions with the objects as (co)domains, meaning that, for $f : A \rightarrow B$ and $g : B \rightarrow A$, $f g$ is not necessarily equivalent to $1_A$. However, for a category of integers, you can't have an integer as a (co)domain for a function (can you?). I guess I'm asking, fundamentally, **how do objects and arrows interact – what is their relationship?**

Comment: Sure you can, you just need to define what you mean.  Order defines arrows in a nice way (as the solution from @jgon points out).

Comment: @Max That would make sense for natural numbers, but not for negative integers.

Comment: @ArnaudD. : right, in my language "integers" without more precision means natural numbers so I often get confused

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure you can. You just have to decide what the mappings between the integers are, and what composition is. For example, one can define the poset category on $\Bbb{Z}$ whose objects are the integers, and has a unique arrow $n\to m$ whenever $n\le m$. You can check that there is a composition defined by transitivity of $\le$ that makes this setup into a category.

Comment: To elaborate, the relation should be a [preorder](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/preorder), i.e. reflexive and transitive.

Comment: Or, you can take *divisibility* as the base relation. Then isomorphism in this category will be $x\cong \pm x$, products in this category will be *greatest common divisor*, and coproducts the *lowest common multiple*.  .....  Or, you can take all the functions as your arrows between sets of form $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$.

Comment: Oh I meant the usual less than or equal to relation, but yeah other appropriate relations work too

Comment: Or you can have a groupoid where the objects are integers but this has absolutely no significance except to imply that there are countably many objects.

Comment: Thanks! Btw, just to clarify, what _is_ that arrow $n → m$? (My guess would be that  it's not a function – something like the pair $(n,m)$.)

Comment: @digitals_ In the given example, yes, the arrows *can be* formally defined as the pairs $(n,m)$ whenever $n$ is in the given relation with $m$, but eventually, they *could be* any other entities, they only need to ensure (for the given example) that there is exactly one arrow $n\to m$ when $n\le m$.

Comment: @digitalis_ Arrows don't have to be anything more than formal arrows. Ok, I know that maybe doesn't clarify anything yet. What I mean is that as long as we have a set $\operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ for each pair of objects $A,B$ in our category, and a composition law that takes $\operatorname{Hom}(B,C)\times \operatorname{Hom}(A,B)$ to $\operatorname{Hom}(A,C)$, the elements of the hom-sets can be anything we want. They don't have to have any other meaning beyond that imposed by the category structure.

Comment: As Berci says, yes, our arrows could be pairs $(n,m)$, but as long as our hom-sets and composition are the same, they could be anything else we can think of. For example, given a bijection $\phi$ of $\Bbb{Z}^2$ with say $\Bbb{N}$, we could relabel all of our original arrows $(n,m)$ by $\phi(n,m)$, and this wouldn't change the structure of the category. To reiterate, arrows in a category don't have any extra structure in general. They're just elements of some hom-set.